# Solving for $f\left(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\right)$ given $g(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\left(f\left(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}\right)}dx$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, integral-equations

How would I solve for a function $f\left(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\right)$ given $g(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\left(f\left(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}\right)}dx$?  I understand that derivatives are the inverse operation of indefinite integral but I'm not sure what the inverse operation of a definite integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is.  How would I solve for $f\left(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\right)$ given a certain function of $g(z)$?

Comment: You need to find $f$ in terms of $g$, do I understand correctly? Is there an explicit expression for $g(z)$? What other properties should $f$ satisfy if any?

Comment: I need to find $f$ in terms of $\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$ using what function I would know $g(z)$ to be.  $g(z)$ could be anything that is a function of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

A hint.

$$g(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f \left( \sqrt{x^2+z^2} \right) \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}=$$

$$=2\int_{0}^{\infty} f \left( \sqrt{x^2+z^2} \right) \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}=\int_{z}^{\infty} f \left( r \right) \frac{dr}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}$$

Where $r=\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$.

We obtained an integral equation, namely a *linear Volterra equation of the first kind*, because one of the integration limits is variable.

$$\frac{1}{2}g(z)=\int_{z}^{\infty} f \left( r \right) \frac{dr}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}} \tag{1}$$

Where *integral kernel* is:

$$K(z,r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}$$.

The methods for solving Volterra equation and other integral equations are present in various literature. You can look something up [here](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ie/ie-toc1.htm) for example.

If think the problem can be reduced to [Abel equation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ie/ie0105.pdf) which has an analytic solution.

Here's how you can do it.

Make a change of variable:

$$r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$$

Then (1) transforms to:

$$\frac{1}{2}g(z)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1/z^2} \frac{1}{y} f \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \right) \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-z^2 y}}$$

$$z g(z)=\int_{0}^{1/z^2} \frac{1}{y} f \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \right) \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1/z^2-y}}$$

Now set:

$$p=\frac{1}{z^2}$$

$$G(p)=z g(z)$$

$$F(y)=\frac{1}{y} f \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \right)$$

Finally you obtain:

> $$G(p)=\int_{0}^{p} F(y) \frac{dy}{\sqrt{p-y}} \tag{2}$$

Which is exactly Abel equation. The solution is provided in the linked file.